# Ignore Symfony routing, serve a folder instead

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Symfony 4 project, it is nothing special but inside `public/blog` I have a  Wordpress project and I would like to serve that folder instead of being processed by Symfony's routing system when I go to "mydomain/blog".

I have this in my .htaccess it is the default config generated by symfony (I think)

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 15M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 15M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I don't undestard how to properly configure this file but I read something about placing this to serve a folder if it exists but still not working, it still being catched by Symfony's routing so I get a 404 error instead

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Mixing totally separate runtime environments in a single install like this is generally going to lead to headache. I'd recommend instead putting your blog under its own distinct install on a 3rd level domain like blog.mydomain.com. Then the Symfony and WordPress apps each live in their own standalone environment (or even on their over servers) and they'll never conflict.

Comment: also this sounds more like a serverfault question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like a bit of a non-answer, but... you shouldn't actually need to do anything special if WordPress (in the `/blog` subdirectory) is correctly configured.

You should already have an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/blog` subdirectory, containing mod_rewrite directives, that handles the URL-routing for WordPress.

For example, the `/blog/.htaccess` file should contain something like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If that's the case then any request to `/blog/<anything>` will already be routed to WordPress. The mod_rewrite directives in the root (Symfony) `.htaccess` file are overridden entirely. (Unless mod_rewrite inheritance has been enabled in the server config; but that seems unlikely.)

However, it's possible that the `/blog/.htaccess` file is incorrect and routing requests back to Symfony. For example, if it's written like the following (the *default* `.htaccess` file), then any request for `/blog/<anything>` will be rewritten to `/index.php` in the document root (ie. Symfony):

```
# !!! THIS IS INCORRECT !!!

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You need to either modify this so it looks like the first `.htaccess` file. Or like the following (which is more the "WordPress way", but essentially does the same thing), for example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The above does the same as the first `.htaccess` file, except the subdirectory is (unnecessarily) hardcoded. If you let WordPress modify the `.htaccess` file then I believe it updates it like this.

You also need to make sure that the WordPress `WP_SITEURL` (Site URL) and `WP_HOME` (Home URL) settings are correctly configured (either in the Dashboard or `wp-config.php` file) to serve files from the `/blog` subdirectory and for `/blog` to be present in the URL.

Note, however, that other non-mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file will still be inherited from the WordPress installation. Although, looking at your directives, this is probably a good thing. Except... if mod_rewrite is not actually enabled on your system, but *I assume* you are already using "pretty" URLs? In which case it must be.